# Trying to start a Fragment from an Activity.

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a tabbed view which I have implemented using Action Bar tabs, now there are one or two pages which navigate away from this tab view. At some point of time I want to call one of the fragments in the foreground again. But I am not finding any example of how to do this.

Class Definition(Fragment1_2):

```
public class Fragment1_2 extends Fragment {
```

Class Definition(AdhocEdit.class):

```
public class AdhocEdit extends Activity{
```

Activity to Fragment Intent so far:

```
Fragment1_2 fragmentB = (Fragment1_2)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragemnt1_2);

        /*  Intent mainIntent;
            mainIntent = new Intent(AdhocEdit.this,Fragment1_2.class); 
            AdhocEdit.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            AdhocEdit.this.finish();    */


        //    startActivity(new Intent(AdhocEdit.this, Fragment1_2.class));
```

Commented because none of them works. Also do I need to add this Fragment1_2 into the Manifest, if so how?

Answer (score 3):

You can't start a fragment like you do for activity.

Fragment is hosted by a activity. You need to add the fragment to the container.

Example from docs

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`fragment_container` is the id of the container which is usually a FrameLayout and you add the desired fragment the container

More info @

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I have bound it with a MainActivity, which hosts it for three tabs, this fragment I open on click of a listview item, MainActivity-->ThreeTabs--->Fragment1_2. Now I want to call it from a different activity. Is this possible AdhocEdit-->MainActivity--->Fragment1_2?

Comment: @user2822178 you need to first navigate to the activity that hosts the frament. You can't start a framgent

Comment: I cannot start it via any method associated with its parent activity?

Comment: @user2822178 there is no concept of start a fragment so you are understanding of fragments is all wrong.

Comment: However, if I allow a method in my MainActivity and update a value inside that method, catch that in the onCreate() and start a FragmentTransactionto the Fragment1_2, I think that will do it for me!

Comment: @user2822178 i suggest you read the docs before commenting further.