# Start a fragment from an activity

Tags: android

I m trying to start a fragment from an activity like this

```
public void btn (View view)
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, F5_fr.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

i have an Onclick thing in my xml with the "btn" :

Fragment 's name is F5_fr.class

Thanks in advance

Comment: having you no idea on fragment?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP is **confused**. (S)he **doesn't appear to even know** what a Fragment is, meaning a **lack in reading the documentation** (which is overabundant) or even doing some **simple research**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to start a Fragment from an Activity.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016194/trying-to-start-a-fragment-from-an-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Snippet. Please refer what is fragment [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, YOUR_FRAGMEMENT,
                        FRAGMENT_TAG(OPTIONAL);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code snippet :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
```

Referance link -  [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm).
here you will get idea of fragments . you can see here how to call a fragments from an activity.

Comment: This post should rather be a **comment**.

Comment: correct.
as i am new here , i will keep this things in mind.
thanks for guiding me :-)

Comment: Tried this. Android studio gives me an error saying `FragmentTransaction cannot be applied`. Anything I am missing here?